# Regarding Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below line in the unix shell script.  I want to exclude test.jar in WEB-INF/lib being added to the CLASSPATH. How can i do it?

```
for file in WEB-INF/lib/*jar ; 

do


CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PWD/$file

done
```

Comment: Arav, please do not reuse the "Regarding Shell script" title for all your questions. Please use a title stating the actual problem. You don't go to the doctor and say "ouch!", do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in WEB-INF/lib/*jar;
do
if [ $file != "WEB-INF/lib/test.jar" ]; then
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PWD/$file
fi
done
```

I have not tried it.

Comment: and add `WEB-INF/lib/` to `test.jar`. I've tried to edit but code formatting disappears.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for file in WEB-INF/lib/!(test).jar
do
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$PWD/$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PWD=$(pwd)

for file in WEB-INF/lib/*jar ; do
    [ "$file" != "test.jar" ] && {
        CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:${PWD}/${file}"
    }
done
```

The code between the braces is only entered if `file` is not 'test.jar' , tweak to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
...
PWD=`pwd`
for file in `ls $PWD/WEB-INF/lib | grep *.jar | grep -v test.jar`
   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
end
```

Comment: don't do that. use shell expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s extglob  
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$(ls !(test).jar|sed "s@^@$PWD/@"|tr "\n" ":"|sed 's/:$//')
```

Or

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$(ls !(genre).txt|awk '{$0="'$PWD'/"$0}1' ORS=":")
```